# Client side authorization when retrieving from server

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, authorization

I have an endpoint to retrieve the user's authorization based on [Joseph Silber's Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/389#issuecomment-464976652).

I have a global `can()` function. It creates a unique key based on the authorization request and sets an object's property based on that key.

```js
can (ability, model = null, id = null) {
  const key = `${ability}_${model}_${id}`
  const params = {
    ability, model, id
  }

  axios.get(this.route('authorize', params))
    .then(res => {
      Vue.set(this.userAuthorizations, key, res.data.allowed)
    })
    .catch(err => this.showError(err.message))

  return key
}
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    userAuthorizations: {}
  }
}
```

So in a template, I do something like...

```html
<button v-if="userAuthorizations[can('create', 'users')]">
  Create User
</button>
```

There will be a delay while it's retrieving the result, but since the key doesn't exist it won't show a restricted thing.

It looks ugly to me, but it's the most sustainable and reusable way I could think to do it on the front-end. Thoughts? What's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind that it is a [ecmascript-8](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-8) feature, instead of waiting for the promise to be fulfilled with a callback:

> ```
> axios.get(this.route('authorize', params))
>    .then(res => {
>      Vue.set(this.userAuthorizations, key, res.data.allowed)
>    })
>    .catch(err => this.showError(err.message))
> ```

the code could wait until the response is retrieved using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
async can (ability, model = null, id = null) {
  const key = `${ability}_${model}_${id}`
  const params = {
    ability, model, id
  }

  const res = await axios.get(this.route('authorize', params))
    .catch(err => this.showError(err.message))

  Vue.set(this.userAuthorizations, key, res.data.allowed)
  return key
}
```

Note that `can()` needs to be declared as `async` in order for `await` to be permitted inside of it.

Comment: I think if I remember correctly, I did use async/await but it didn't play nice as a `v-if`. I could be misremembering. Doing this would also change the conditional right? So `v-if="can('create', 'users')`

Comment: That probably would be an issue... is there a way to fetch the data in a lifecycle hook like `created()`, `mounted()`, etc. or would there be an indeterminate amount of parameters?